# AutoIt GUICtrlRead Specials characters

Tags: autoit

autoit GUICtrlCreateInput special char ignored ?

```
$user = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 90, 65, 100, 20)
$dom = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 90, 95, 100, 20)
$pass = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 90, 125, 100, 20, 0x0020)

Send(GUICtrlRead($user) & "{tab}" & GUICtrlRead($dom) & "{tab}" & GUICtrlRead($pass) & "{Enter}")
```

Example with : "TOTO" as user, "home" as dom and, "azerty+" as password.
Output will be :

```
TOTO    home    azerty
```

Why GUICtrlRead() ignore specials characters as my "+" char ?

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the help file:

**Send()**
Sends simulated keystrokes to the active window.

Send ( "keys" [, flag] )

Parameters

- *keys* - The sequence of keys to send.
- *flag [optional]* - Changes how "keys" is processed:   flag = 0
  (default), Text contains special characters like + and ! to indicate
  SHIFT and ALT key-presses.   flag = 1, keys are sent raw.

So, your example is missing flag set to 1.

```
$user = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 90, 65, 100, 20)
$dom = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 90, 95, 100, 20)
$pass = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 90, 125, 100, 20, 0x0020)

Send(GUICtrlRead($user),1)
Send("{tab}")
Send(GUICtrlRead($dom),1)
Send("{tab}")
Send(GUICtrlRead($pass),1)
Send("{Enter}")
```