# Pass special characters with BAT file

Tags: batch-file, variables, cmd, special-characters, autoit

I have variable: `K+$>P9Z<>>n+Gb=`and I would like to pass it to bat file.

The issue is that even if I close it with "", it just opening and closing in millisecond.

**AutoIt:**

```
Case $msg = $MAIN
        $NJN = GUICtrlRead($NJN_set)
        $OJN = GUICtrlRead($OJN_set)
        $PASS = GUICtrlRead($PASS_set)
        Run("n:\xxx\xxx\xxx.bat" & " " & $NJN  & " " & $OJN  & " " & $PASS)
```

**xxx.BAT:**

```
call n:\xxxx\var\variables.bat %1 %2 %3
set yourZipPassword=%Password%
```

Comment: And where is `%password%` set? If thats in variables.bat there might be the problem... A useful thing almost always is placing `echo` and `pause` all over your batch-files to determine where to problem might occur.

Comment: I used autoIt ,all variables are passing normally except this one. I have tried to use pause, BUT bat file closing even after first line where I passing the values, (P.S. I have used "" and still no luck)

Comment: In xxx.BAT before passing the values have you tried `echo %1 pause` and double quotes? I assume that the error is not within the passing of the variables but more likely within variables.bat... Additionally have you tried to start the batch-file manually? If you know the values, open a command prompt and start the batch-file with the values you have got. This will prevent the window from closing and you can check for potential error messages.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 if I place directly this password, everything working fine. So issue with how AutoIt passing this data is it?

Comment: Would be the conclusion I think... Unfortunately I do not know AutoIt so I am not able to find your problem there...

Comment: Can be closed as it went to out-of topic((((

Comment: This is solution, which solves the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080031/autoit-guictrlread-specials-characters

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic > can no longer be reproduced.

Answer (score 2):

What does your batch file do?

To check whether the variable is passed to the batch file correctly, you can print its value in the console by adding `echo %[NAME_OF_YOUR_VARIABLE]%`, e.g. if you type: `do_something.bat K+$>P9Z<>>n+Gb=` your batch file might start like this:

```
@echo off
set parameter1=%1
echo %parameter1%
```

The problem here is, that `>>` are a reserved string for redirecting streams. I tried the following. Call
`do_something.bat "K+$>P9Z<>>n+Gb="`
while your batch file starts with

```
set var=%1
set var=%var:"=%
```

The first line accepts the first argument and stores it in the variable var. The second statement replaces the double quotes with nothing (=removes) the double quotes from the variable. You might find more information about escaping characters here in this article: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php

Comment: I call n:\xxxxx\var\variables.bat %1 %2 %3 with AutoIt, and variable passed to bat file. Where I have set yourZipPassword=%Password%

Comment: Key point it that BAT file not even want to load because of this variable.

Comment: The problem seems to be the two ```>>```. You have to put the whole string into quotes: ```"K+$>P9Z<>>n+Gb="``` or escape them as in this article: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Try "K+$>P9Z<>>n+Gb=" as in the updated example above.

Comment: the issue is not with accepting or not accepting the variable, the bat file would not like to work with this variable. I click bat file and i's opens and closed after a millisecond.

Comment: To have the script pause at a specific locations, add ```pause``` commands.

Comment: As Michael stated in another answer: You might add a caret ^ in front of each < and each > character to have it be interpreted as a regular character without any special meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Use a caret `^`. To escape a character try using a caret. Try this:

```
K+$^>P9Z^<^>^>n+Gb=
```

We wil escape the arrows. The arrows try to point for a file to output too.